# How to redirect network traffic using squid and nginx to outer page?

Tags: nginx, proxy, squid

My school network blocks access to game pages, more exactly colonist.io. We have an access to linux server for learning purposes. I'd like to avoid blocking by setting up some kind of proxy server on said linux server through which I could forward all the traffic. I read about squid but I can't make it work. Idea is to write server url in the browser and that it redirects all the traffic to colonist.io, receives an answer and gives it back to me. Server can receive curl to colonist.io but I get blocked access when using browser. I have already installed squid but I have a problem configuring it to make all the traffic flow through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. My friend solved it using port forwarding without nginx or squid.

For example:

> ssh -d 9898 username@ipadress

Then go to Firefox -> Settings -> Network settings:

1. Check radio button *Manual proxy configuration*
2. SOCKS Host 127.0.0.1 Port 9898
3. Check radio button SOCKS v5
4. Check checkbox Proxy DNS when using SOCKS v5
5. Press OK

You can use any other port you want, it doesn't have to be 9898.